# My site was removed from one keyword

Tags: seo, google, google-search

one day I noticed that my site was crawled by google and after this crawl my website was removed from one keyword. It may have been error on my part because I made menu item with thas tag as H1, maybe search engine classified it as keyword abuse, now I removed H1 tag from menu. What should I do to get my site back on this keyword?

Paulius,